# Laravel Eloquent/Fluent select top 1 row per group

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, greatest-n-per-group

I need to determine if a given row has a `signed_out` or `signed_in` date that is older than one year. Sometimes a territory may be signed out currently which is specified by a `NULL` value. If this is the case, I need to look to the next highest `signed_in` value to determine if the territory has been signed out within a year. Otherwise, I need to look at the last `signed_in` date per group to determine this.

The groups are based on the `territory_id` column.

My table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| id | territory_id | signed_out          | signed_in           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 5  | 8            | 2012-12-09 00:00:00 | 2013-02-28 00:00:00 |
| 9  | 8            | 2014-03-23 14:48:17 | 2014-06-11 00:00:00 |
| 11 | 10           | 2014-06-25 11:07:59 | NULL                |
| 14 | 10           | 2012-06-27 21:28:17 | 2012-10-10 00:00:00 |
| 15 | 11           | 2014-06-27 21:28:48 | NULL                |
| 13 | 11           | 2012-09-12 20:23:07 | 2012-12-27 00:00:00 |
| 20 | 11           | 2011-10-30 21:05:29 | 2012-01-05 00:00:00 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Results: Rows `9`, `11`, `15`

I've looked at many examples of `group by` and `greatest-n-per-group` tagged mysql questions but I can't wrap my head around how to build this query, especially in `Laravel` using Eloquent or Fluent. If I have to use a Raw query, that's fine I guess.

What I've tried:

```
TerritoriesSignInOut::where('signed_in', '<=', Carbon::now()->subYear())
                    ->orWhere(function($query)
                    {
                        $query->where('signed_out', '<=', Carbon::now()->subYear())
                              ->whereNull('signed_in');
                    })
                    ->groupBy('territory_id')
                    ->orderBy('signed_in', 'DESC')
                    ->get();
```

but that doesn't perform the right subquery select which is what I think the issue is with that statement.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I've been racking my brain over this for hours.

Comment: Would there be any way you can show another grid of the results you expect to get back from MySQL if this was working correctly?

Comment: I did just add expected results. I'll take a look at your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this query should work for you, though you might want to test it first.  It seemed to work for me with the data you provided.

```
SELECT id, GREATEST(signed_in, COALESCE(signed_out, signed_in)) AS `my_date`
FROM (SELECT * FROM `territories` ORDER BY signed_in DESC) territories
GROUP BY territory_id
HAVING my_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

To build the query in Fluent, this should work.  It uses quite a bit of raw but I figure if you aren't binding any data, there is no chance of injection.

```
DB::table(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM `territories` ORDER BY signed_in DESC) territories'))
    ->select(DB::raw('id, GREATEST(signed_in, COALESCE(signed_out, signed_in)) AS `my_date`'))
    ->groupBy('territory_id')
    ->having('my_date', '<=', DB::raw('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)'))
    ->get();
```

You would have to change the name of the table though, I just used territories because it was easy, but it's obviously not a territories table.

Comment: Excellent! Works great. I had to just change the first `DB::raw` `ORDER BY` to `ASC` and removed the `COALESCE` function since in some cases I do need rows that contain `NULL` values in the `signed_in` column.